# VB2008 Type Cast Exception

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have a form that has a textbox (say TextBox1). This field is of string type.

On clicking on a button, I have the below code

```
Dim field1 As String

If (TextBox1.Text) Then field1 = TextBox1.Text Else MsgBox("TextBox1 Code can not be empty. Enter proper value!", vbCritical, "Empty TextBox1")
```

I built the solution and ran it. When the form is opened, I did not enter anything in TextBox1. I clicked on the button. It throws an exception as below:

```
InvalidCastException was unhandled
Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.
```

Can anyone guide as to how can I handle this exception? Also, why is it trying to convert my string to a Bool anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this part:

```
If (TextBox1.Text)
```

It's trying to convert `TextBox1.Text` to `Boolean` to see whether or not to go into the block. You might have meant:

```
If (TextBox1.Text <> "")
```

Comment: Probably yes! I tried something like this `I finally, figured out :-)

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then MsgBox("TextBox1 Code can not be empty. Enter proper value!", vbCritical, "Empty TextBox1") Else field1 = TextBox1.Text` and it worked :) Thanks for your time Jon!

Comment: @Bhavani: I could be wrong, but I don't *think* `TextBox.Text` will ever be null.